# VBA Sub not defined for Solver

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

The following line of code is giving me Sub or Function not defined whenever I try to use it. I've tried double checking my spelling, renaming it, looking up other questions online (most other mistakes were forgetting to add an s after sheets or worksheets), but I have no idea what's wrong with my code. I originally got this code from the macro recorder.

I am using this sub multiple times on different sheets, but that hasn't affected my other subs that are similar.

```
Sub SolverSolver()

    SolverOk SetCell:="$G$3", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$4,$G$6", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve

End Sub
```

Maybe the way in which it's being used is what's wrong, so I've added the way in which its called below. This line is in a large sub of simple commands like giving a cell a name, and this large simple sub also repeats multiple times. However even when attempting to run the sub by directly running it though the developer tab, it still has the same error so I don't think its the way the sub is called.

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(630.75, 52.5, 74.25, 26.25).OnAction = "SolverSolver"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is that `SolverSolver` in a module or in a class module?

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I check? I've never had any schooling in vba and had to pick it up for my job that started last week.

Comment: Is it in a module listed under `Modules`, or is it in a worksheet code module or a class?

Comment: Its a worksheet code module.

Comment: Then no wonder you cannot call it by name alone. It must be qualified with the code module name, or move it to a plain module.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You dont have reference set to `Solver`. To use Solver functions that'
s manadatory. Set it like this: in VBA editor,  Go to Tools --> References  --> and select Solver. Click OK.

[image]

Also make sure that you have enabled the Solver Add-In, In Excel you can enable it by File--> Options --> Add-ins , here selecet Excel Add-Ins under manage dropdown and click go. On The next screen check Sover Add-In and click OK.

---

As GSerg mentioned, if your SolverSolver sub is in a sheet module , then you need to include the module name in action param value. So if sheet1 contains the sub then

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(630.75, 52.5, 74.25, 26.25).OnAction = "Sheet1.SolverSolver"
```

Comment: @upvoter The OP fails to call their own procedure `SolverSolver`, not the Solver routines called from inside it.

Comment: That's gotten me farther thanks, It gives me an error of object not defined for the SolverSolve line, but it still solves fine? Thanks guys, I might just go without adding a solver function as there isn't really that much to it.

Comment: That did it! Thanks guys!

Comment: Another issue that may come up if Excel is updated is that the Solver reference may not work even though it is checked. If you think this is the case, uncheck Solver and save, then re-check it and save (hit "OK") to get it to reactivate.